# Scallable, multilogin server/client architecture that cannot push messages to clients (only pull)

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

I am conceiving client/server architecture for application that has pretty old-school server-side code I cannot modify myself; It can only send data to client as response to direct client's query - think of it like old school AJAX (through it is not browser based). The server specifically cannot *push* information to any client without query.

The problem is my client allows multi-login and as such some data may be changed elsewhere, while the client is unaware (until next query). I also accept client-to-client collaboration (with server serving only as helper and optional NAT hole puncher)

Now for the actual questions: which design/code patterns would be useful in such scenario, where the app should be scallable and maintainable? I already googled Command/Query separation pattern, but subscribing to events would be silly, as no event can come without query (which would induce constant checking for events...)

One more thing - the server code does not support transactions, only sort of check (read returns version code which subsequent write may post back. If the version noted by write op differs from read it means the data was changed in between and error code is returned)

Answer (score 1):

You really don’t have many options here.  If you only control the client code then having the client poll the server is about the only way to go.

Using the client to client collaboration you could implement a roll-your-own messaging system so anytime a client updates an entity it sends a message to all connected clients saying “entity XXX with ID 123 has been changed”, then each client decides for itself if it needs to refresh.  That same idea using a real message queue would be better, but it sounds like you have connectivity restrictions if you need to use the server as a “NAT hole puncher”.

Comment: Yes, I know - I am looking for design patterns to implement that - especially server/client part :)